# 2 Layer Finite Difference Scheme PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem, finite-difference-methods

I have this PDE, and I need to build a 2 layer Finite Difference scheme for it.

$\frac{∂^2}{∂x^2}(k(x,t) \frac{∂^2U(x,t)}{∂t^2})=0$

k is just a parameter, which is dependent on x and t. The problem is there are second order derivatives, and I don't know how to couple them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to define a grid for the finite difference scheme. I will be using a regular gird here, but the same approach can be used for an irregular grid if the appropriate approximations to derivatives are used. The grid is
$$
x_i = x_0 + i\cdot\Delta x
\quad\quad
t_j = t_0 + j\cdot\Delta t
$$
and for a general funciton $f(x,t)$, define
$$
f_{i,j} = f(x_i,t_j)
$$
which, on a uniform grid, has approximations to its (unmixed) second derivatives
$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)_{i,j} = \frac{f_{i+1,j} - 2f_{i,j} + f_{i-1,j}}{\Delta x^2}
$$
$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}\right)_{i,j} = \frac{f_{i,j+1} - 2f_{i,j} + f_{i,j-1}}{\Delta t^2}.
$$

For your given equation, we first define
$$
F(x,t) = k(x,t) \cdot \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}(x,t)
$$
thus
$$
0 = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}(x,t).
$$
Discretising:
\begin{align}
0
&= \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}\left[F_{i+1,j} - 2F_{i,j} + F_{i-1,j}\right]
\\
&= \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}\left[k_{i+1,j}\left(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}\right)_{i+1,j} - 2k_{i,j}\left(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}\right)_{i,j} + k_{i-1,j}\left(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}\right)_{i-1,j}\right]
\\
&= \frac{1}{\Delta x^2\Delta t^2}\left[k_{i+1,j}\left(U_{i+1,j+1}-2U_{i+1,j}+U_{i+1,j-1}\right) - 2k_{i,j}\left(U_{i,j+1}-2U_{i,j}+U_{i,j-1}\right) + 
k_{i-1,j}\left(U_{i-1,j+1}-2U_{i-1,j}+U_{i-1,j-1}\right)\right].
\end{align}
To use this in a finite difference scheme you will need to specify $U_{i,j}$ at the first two time instances, as well as the left and right endpoints.